# How can I make sure my server reads what the client has written?

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream

I am writing a byte array from a socket client as:

```
byte[] arr = { 49, 49, 49, 49, 49};

InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
connection = new Socket(address, port);
out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
```

At receiving end, on the server I have:

```
byte[] msgType = new byte[5];
in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
int bytesRead = in.read(msgType, 0, 5);

System.out.println("msg rcvd: " + msgType.toString());
```

In the output I get weird string:

```
server: waiting for connection
server: connection received from localhost
server: Connection Successful
bytes read: 5
msg rcvd: ��w
```

How can make sure I get same bytes as I sent from my client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an `ObjectOutputStream` on one side, you'll have to use an `ObjectInputStream` at the other side.

In your case, a simple OutputStream (maybe buffered) and `.write()` and `.read()` will do.

But for printing, don't use `byte[].toString()`, use `Arrays.toString()` if you want to have a formatted output.

---

Edit: I just see you are not even writing your array on the sending side. So you are actually only reading the ObjectOutputStream header.

---

From the comment:

> I am handling server side and I am told that I would be send a byte array. How
>   do I receive and print that byte array ? byte array in this case is bytes of text/strings

This sounds like the server sends something like simply the Strings encoded in some encoding, like ASCII, UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1. If so, on the receiving end you can use something like this:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
BufferedReader in =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),
                                             encoding));
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Of course, make sure the encoding is the same encoding as actually used on the sending side.

The corresponding sending code could be something like this:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
Writer w =
    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),
                                              encoding));
w.write("Hello World!\n");
w.write("And another line.\n");
w.flush();
```

Comment: agreed, if you use ObjectOutputStream, or ObjectInputStream, you must use both. In this case, you need neither.

Comment: @meBigFatGuy - how can i make sure client side uses same stream as server side. I am handling server side and I am told that I would be send a byte array. How do I receive and print that byte array ? byte array in this case is bytes of text/strings.

Comment: @Paulo - Thanks ! I think I need to tell you my exact use case as I tihnk u might be able to help me understand how to handle this. My msg structore is something like - byte 1 - msg code, byte 2-5 - msg length, followed by message content. Message content is binary text, which I also plan to handle the way you sent but code and length are integers. Also complete message is sent as byte[]. so, how can I get first byte, then next 4 bytes and then byte[] of binary text.

Comment: If you have a specified binary protocol, use DataInputStream/DataOutputStream (instead of a Reader/Writer) to implement it from the Java side. It has methods to read integers from bytes, and also a method to read an array of specified size fully (for the message content). Then you can use new String(byte[], encoding) to convert the text part (if it actually is text representable as a string).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what are trying to print out, but I can tell you that `msgType.toString()` will not print the contents of the byte array.

[Here](http://tomaranand.blogspot.com/2008/03/print-hexstream-java.html) is a link I found to a method which will print out the byte array in a more meaningful fashion.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the same bytes, it's just a matter of how you interpret them. If you want to see the bytes as a `String` use this instead:

```
System.out.println("msg rcvd: " + new String(msgType, "UTF-8"));
```

Be careful that the bytes you're dealing have the right encoding though (I assumed UTF-8 here). Since you're already `ObjectOutputStream` though, you could just use its `writeUTF()` on the server side and `ObjectInputStream.readUTF()` on the client side.